# JSX isn't returning anything

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have this code in my component, I can see that there are values evaluated when I debug, but when the code finishes executing, I don't see anything in the result, is there something wrong with my JSX?

```
export default class TilesComponent extends React.Component<ITilesComponentProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITilesComponentProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.tiles}>
        {this.props.structure.tiles != null &&

          this.props.structure.tiles.map((tile) => {
                {(
                <div className="tile">
                  <h1>{tile.tileName}</h1>
                  <h2>wassup</h2>
                </div>
                ) 
            }
        })}
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Am still new to react/jsx, so I might be writing something wrong.

thank you.

Comment: Remove extra open { and close } after tiles.map((tile) => { this

Comment: @Think-Twice that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction required inside map

Wrong one:

```
   this.props.structure.tiles.map((tile) => {
            {(
            <div className="tile">
              <h1>{tile.tileName}</h1>
              <h2>wassup</h2>
            </div>
            ) 
        }
    })}
```

Right one:

```
 this.props.structure.tiles.map((tile) => {
            return (
            <div className="tile">
              <h1>{tile.tileName}</h1>
              <h2>wassup</h2>
            </div>
            ) 
    })
```

Full snippet:

```
      export default class TilesComponent extends    React.Component<ITilesComponentProps, {}> {
      public render():    React.ReactElement<ITilesComponentProps> {
     return (
        <div className={styles.tiles}>
            {this.props.structure.tiles != null &&

             this.props.structure.tiles.map((tile) => {
                  return(
                   <div className="tile">
                      <h1>{tile.tileName}</h1>
                     <h2>wassup</h2>
                  </div>
                )
            })}
         </div>
         )
       }
     }
```

Comment: How about the 1st return statement? do I remove it? can you please post the complete snippet so I can understand it? thanks

Comment: First `return` belongs to the `render` method and you should keep it as you figured out :) If you are new to React, maybe it is better to go through the official documentation.

Comment: @devserkan I did go through the docs, just trying it out on a real app to learn, so somethings would be confusing when trying to apply the concepts :)

Comment: Yeah as @devserkan mentioned try to understand the concepts so that it will be easy for to apply them in code. You will learn more in React. Keep learning. Good luck